# ETL with Talend + AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, etl, talend

Background: I want to building up the ETL with the drag and drop function in Talend

Question: May I know whether the Talend can compose the ETL built with drag and drop into the Redshift SQL, and run the ETL in the Redshift directly, instead of running the ETL in Talend server runtime environment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Talend has a SQL module but you will need to write the SQL for the module.